# Резиновый дизайн с TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть `TableLayoutPanel`, в нем `k` столбцов и `k` строк.

```
table = new TableLayoutPanel
{
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};
table.RowStyles.Clear();
table.ColumnStyles.Clear();
for (var k = 0; k < Order; k++)
{
    table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100 / Order));
    table.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100 / Order));
}
```

Затем в каждую строку и столбец я вставляю `Label` с текстом:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Order; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < Order; j++)
    {
        table.Controls.Add(new Label
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            Font = new Font("Webdings", 72, FontStyle.Regular),
            Text = ""
        }, i, j);
    }
```

При изменении размеров окна при `k = 4` форма еще более менее хорошо и быстро отрисовывается, но при `k = 8` форма ведет себя странно и при разворачивании окна на весь экран отрисовывается секунды 2-3 и при отрисовке выглядит странно. В чем дело?

[image: Как выглядит форма при отрисовке]

Comment: Странно, на скриншоте не видно, но на самой форме центральные ячейки не были отрисованы и "штук" как в левом верхнем углу больше. И конечно в вопросе дизайнерские строки кода, по типу "цвет текста", я опустил.

Comment: Я разобрался, все дело было в обводке ячеек таблиц, они криво отрисовывались